# Wordpress auto added "p" & "div" tag question

Tags: php, wordpress, tags

everyone.
If you know why added `</p></div>` in wordpress.

origin file not `<div><p>` line.
[origin wordpress php file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gtiYg.png)

but, in wordpress upload contents has show `</p></div>`
how to delete `</p></div>` ????

[in wordpress show error code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VrKyY.png)

Answer (score 0):

This is beacause of [wpautop()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/) function which replaces double line-breaks with paragraph elements, to disable it, add this to your functions.php file:

```
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
```